# Screen scape altered info from another website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying if it is possible to get the result of another site after clicking some items and altering some data on that site.

For example, you have a site which asks you first for some input and then gives a result. This result i want to have and save it to a database and display it on my own site. Is there any possibility for this?

I searched for hours and i can only find static examples.

Any help or link would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  Use fiddler to detect what the form post (assuming its a form post) looks like.  You can then recreate the post using an HttpWebRequest and swap your unique values in.